# Alert only once with simple condition

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, alert

I made a very simple alert using javascript:

```
if(progressLeft == 0){
    alert("You are finished!, create your next exercise!");
}
```

It is supposed to alert the user when progressLeft hits 0. This value gets decucted in value till it reaches 0. but ofcourse if it does it stays there thus making me stuck with the alert. 
This eems like something easy  to solve but im quite new to javascript programming. What can i do to overcome this?

Comment: Change `progressLeft` to something other than 0 in there?

Comment: add more code..

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I want the alert to show when progressleft hits 0. Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you're stuck with the alert that means the above code is inside a loop. It shouldn't be though, it should run after each time `progressLeft` changes instead.

Comment: Add `progressLeft = -1` before the `alert`.

Comment: This seems more of a logical issue that you are facing. The progressLeft variable is the key decider of alert execution. Comment by @DigitalDrifter seems a promising solution to your problem unless the variable needs to be 0

Comment: You need to post more relevant code, or people have no choice but to keep guessing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could introduce another variable, called `altertShown`.
Just use it like this:

```js
var alertShown = false; /* ATTENTION: Declare this somewhere out of the function in global scope! */
if(progressLeft == 0){
    if(!alertShown) {
        alertShown = true;
        alert("You are finished!, create your next exercise!");
    }
} else {
    alertShown = false;
}
```